Example of object that is not a class or a proper class
Whilst starting to read Rotman's book on homological algebra, it starts with a discussion on set theoretical issues of categories, stating at the start that
"As a practical matter, when an
alleged class arises, there are three possibilities: it is a set; it is a proper class;
it is not a class at all (one consequence of the axioms is that a proper class
is forbidden to be an element of any class)"
Bit later we get a definition that $\text{Nat}(F,G)=\{\text{natural transformations }F\to G\}$ and comment that "The notation $\text{Nat}(F, G)$ should be accepted in light of our remarks on Set
Theory on page 8. In general, $\text{Nat}(F, G)$ may not be a class and, even if it
is a class, it may be a proper class"
What could be examples of such objects that are not classes or proper classes?

If $F$ and $G$ are "large" then $\mathrm{Nat}(F,G)$ is a collection of proper classes and so not a class. Similarly, the collection of all classes is not a class, proper or otherwise. Terms like "hyperclass" and "conglomerate" get used here sometimes.
